# Responsive img using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

I've been trying to use the Bootstrap grid in my system but encounter this problem. below is a sample code.

What I want is both my columns to have the same height. the 1st column is for description and the 2nd is for the image. The problem is when my description is too long the image doesn't give the same height as the first.

## Output :

[image: here's the output]

## Expected Result :

[image: expected result]

What I want is for the image to be the same height like column 1.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-6 testcolumn1">
             col-sm-6<br><br>col-sm-6<br><br>col-sm-6<br><br>col-sm-6<br><br>col-sm-6<br><br>col-sm-6<br> 
             <br>col-sm-6<br><br>col-sm-6<br><br>col-sm-6<br><br>col-sm-6<br><br>col-sm-6<br><br>col-sm- 
             6<br><br>col-sm-6<br><br>col-sm-6<br><br>col-sm-6<br><br>col-sm-6<br><br>col-sm-6<br><br>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-6 testcolumn2">
             <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcT1KPZfwCoqjBUtGsUVhEz3ChuxcAJa3MQ7IsCwzC6z3dt6eyS-">
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.row-eq-height {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

[class*="col-"] {
  float: none;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.bgimag {
  background: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcT1KPZfwCoqjBUtGsUVhEz3ChuxcAJa3MQ7IsCwzC6z3dt6eyS-);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col col-sm-6 testcolumn1">
      col-sm-6<br><br>col-sm-6<br><br>col-sm-6<br><br>col-sm-6<br><br>col-sm-6<br><br>col-sm-6<br>
      <br>col-sm-6<br><br>col-sm-6<br><br>col-sm-6<br><br>col-sm-6<br><br>col-sm-6<br><br>col-sm- 6
      <br><br>col-sm-6<br><br>col-sm-6<br><br>col-sm-6<br><br>col-sm-6<br><br>col-sm-6<br><br>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-sm-6 testcolumn2 bgimag">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but the image height still didn't resize like in column 1.

Comment: share  your expected scrrenshot

Comment: you can see the output on my post. but what i want for the image is to be the same length/height of the column 1. the image height will adjust automatically, it depends on the height of column 1. thanks

Comment: I Want your expected screenshot?

Comment: check it in my post. click the link for expected result

Comment: Thank you but image stretched its ok?

Comment: i think image-rendering will fix that.

Comment: Updated check now

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you could but you shouldn't. The image is going to be distorted based on your question description. You could use of the class img-responsive (bootstrap 3) or img-fluid (bootstrap 4) but what it does is adjusting the width based on certain breakpoints. I'm no expert but I think you're going to create a new class for it.